# EditForm with extended functionality without writing html part

Tags: blazor

I would like to have `EditForm` that will notify me when unsaved changes are present.

[image]

It's easily done with `EditContext` and `EditContext.OnFieldChanged` event handler ([Working demo](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QbuFFtls57J3CalF37)):

```cs
    
 <EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnValidSubmit="()=> isUnsavedChangePresent=false">
   <span>@(isUnsavedChangePresent?"changes are not saved!": "changes are saved")</span>
    <InputText @bind-Value="product.Name" />
    <button >Save it </button>
    <div>(state is updated after focus change)</div>
 </EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext editContext;
    Product product= new Product();
   bool isUnsavedChangePresent;
    private async void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object? sender,FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      isUnsavedChangePresent = true;
    }
    class Product
    {
     public string Name {get;set;}
    }

     protected override  void OnParametersSet()
    {
      editContext = new EditContext(product);
      editContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
    }
}
```

I would like to have this `EditForm` as own component, so I tried this:

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@inherits EditForm
@ChildContent(EditContext) @*is this correct?? It throws error about cascading parameters*@
@code
{

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        this.EditContext = new EditContext(this.Model);
        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
    }

    private async void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In On Filed Changed");
    }

}
```

I would like to use HTML part from parent `EditForm`, but I don't know how or if it's even possible..

Comment: I suggest to you to write your own component `<ChangesWatcher`. You can access to EditContext via cascade parameters.

Comment: @daniherrera Thanks, that is great solution, much cleaner then I was hoping. (can you turn your comment into the answer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code describes how you can define a generic class deriving from the EditForm component...

### ExtendedEditForm.cs (place it in the Pages folder)

```
public partial class ExtendedEditForm <T> : EditForm
    {
        [Parameter]
        public T MyModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            EditContext = new EditContext(MyModel);
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
           
            base.OnInitialized();
        }


        private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName);

        }
    }
```

### Usage

```
@page "/"

<ExtendedEditForm MyModel="product" OnValidSubmit ="OnValidSubmit">
    <span>@(IsSaved ? "changes are saved" : "changes are not saved!" )</span>
    <InputText @bind-Value="product.Name" />
    <button type="submit">Save it </button>
    <div>(state is updated after focus change)</div>
</ExtendedEditForm>
    
@code {
       
    Product product = new Product();

    private bool IsSaved { get; set; }

    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        IsSaved = true;
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note: It is not clear why you should subclass the EditForm component. You may do so if a need is aroused, but not in the case of your code sample, which is trivial.

You should create and initialize your objects such as the EditContext in the OnInitialized(Async) methods, not in the OnParametersSet(Async) methods.

Using the EditContext.OnFieldChanged to set the value of isUnsavedChangePresent is wrong, though in this case it works...Suppose that you have 10 fields in your form instead of one. In any case, you should do that in the `OnValidSubmit` event handler that is triggered when you click the "submit" button. You should place a "submit" button instead (or in addition) to the button element.

```
@ChildContent(EditContext) @*is this correct?? It throws error about cascading parameters*@
```

No, it's not correct. The ChildContent property is inherited from the EditForm, your derived class does not override the BuildRenderTree method that renders the EditForm, and uses the ChildContent in its rendering procedure. You just do nothing... no code in that regards. Note that override the BuildRenderTree method can be done in two ways: In code, by overriding the BuildRenderTree or by creating the view part of your component (Razor markups and C#) (.razor)

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for. Thank you. Also thanks for your notes and explanations. Only thing I don't have complete understanding is `IsSaved` vs `isUnsavedChangePresent`. Because they are not complete oposit. On the initialization `IsSaved` gonna be false, but no changes are present (thus no need to notify user). After change it should notify, but `IsSaved` is same.  That is why I think `OnFieldChanged` is necessary.

Comment: IsSaved is the short name I gave for isUnsavedChangePresent .  OK I understand what you want to achieve. Change your code to this: IsSaved ? "" : "changes are not saved!" And define the IsSaved property with the default value of true. Now, when your app runs for the first time IsSaved is true, and thus no message is displayed. In the EditContext_OnFieldChanged method add: IsSaved = false; which causes the message  "changes are not saved!" to be displayed when the user starts editing. Finally, when the user click the "submit" button IsSaved is set to true, causing the message to disappear...

Answer (score 0):

In Net 6 I did something similar, I wanted to extend EditForm to accept a Change Event, because I want to trigger change without pushing a submit button. Maybe this example can help someone

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;

namespace HOLOblazor.Components.Form;

public partial class EditFormChange : EditForm
{
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnPropertyChange {  get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();
        EditContext.OnFieldChanged -= EditContext_OnFieldChanged; // Unsuscribe old parameters set
        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
    }

    private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EditContext.Validate())
            OnPropertyChange.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

And now I can do

```
<EditFormChange Model="mymodel" OnPropertyChange="() => UpdateForm(mymodel)">
    <FluentValidationValidator />
    <InputText @bind-Value="mymodel.Field1" />
    <small class="form-text text-muted"><ValidationMessage For="() => mymodel.Field1" /></small>
</EditFormChange>
```